# Crash on GhostBSD/FreeBSD GNOME

Tags: wxwidgets, freebsd

I met an issue with wxWidgets 3.1.2 on GhostBSD 19.04 which is a FreeBSD with GNOME desktop. The build of my App looks OK but it crashed on
initializing globals. The same apps works OK on other Linux dists.

I've no idea so I tried the minimal example of wxWidgets. It crashed at the same point. I tried truss which is the equivalent of strace of F
reeBSD. Has anyone solved the same issue?

I used g++(g++ (FreeBSD Ports Collection) 8.3.0) to build wxWidgets. And it can not be debugged by gdb because it crashed at global init. Below is the call stack. Line 205 is the last line of minimal.cpp.

Core was generated by `./minimal'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

```
#0 0x0000000802a98a38 in vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info () from /lib/libcxxrt.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0 0x0000000802a98a38 in vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info () at /lib/libcxxrt.so.1
#1 0x0000000801a52006 in __dynamic_cast () at /usr/local/lib/gcc8/libstdc++.so.6
#2 0x0000000801ad0620 in bool std::has_facet<std::ctype<char> >(std::locale const&) () at /usr/local/lib/gcc8/libstdc++.so.6
#3 0x0000000801ac3cb4 in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_cache_locale(std::locale const&) ()
at /usr/local/lib/gcc8/libstdc++.so.6
#4 0x0000000801ac4130 in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) ()
at /usr/local/lib/gcc8/libstdc++.so.6
#5 0x0000000801a65a33 in std::ios_base::Init::Init() () at /usr/local/lib/gcc8/libstdc++.so.6
#6 0x000000000046ec5f in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535)
at /usr/local/lib/gcc8/include/c++/iostream:74
#7 0x000000000046ee86 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_minimal.cpp(void) () at ./minimal.cpp:205
#8 0x0000000800aec3bd in () at /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#9 0x0000000800b050b0 in () at /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#10 0x0000000800b09000 in ()
#11 0x00007fffffffe710 in ()
#12 0x00007fffffffeaa2 in ()
#13 0x00007fffffffd830 in ()
#14 0x0000000800af7049 in () at /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#15 0x00007fffffffd850 in ()
#16 0x0000000800aebf12 in () at /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#17 0x0000000800b18a20 in ()
#18 0x00007fffffffe710 in ()
#19 0x0000000802ab0ce0 in ()
#20 0x0000000800b1fc00 in ()
#21 0x0000000800b18200 in ()
#22 0x00007fffffffe710 in ()
#23 0x00007fffffffd890 in ()
#24 0x0000000800af06ed in () at /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
#25 0x0000000800b181e0 in ()
#26 0x00007fffffffe710 in ()
```

SIGNAL 11 (SIGSEGV) code=SEGV_ACCERR trapno=12 by truss

Comment: Did you try with non-wxWidgets minimal code? Something like `int main() { return -1; }`

Comment: Check that you compiled wxWidgets and your own application with the same compiler version and the same options as this definitely looks like some kind of ABI conflict.

Comment: @mingli, how did you configure wxWidgets build?